# How to set default value for FilteringSelect widget in Dojo Data Grid?

Tags: select, datagrid, dojo, filtering

I am trying to display dynamic values read for a store as options within a `filteringSelect` widget in my DOJO Data Grid. The values are getting populated as expected however, I am unable to display a default value when the grid loads, right now it shows up as "..." on single click, I am able to see a drop down.

Below is the location of the sample code:

http://jsfiddle.net/R64bE/2/

I want to iterate through my "myStore" in the code above and make the item with `label = 'Y'` as the default for that `filteringSelect`.

I want the default value displayed as soon as the grid or filtering select is rendered. Any pointers or sample code will be of great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad that I was able to fixed it too..Below is the code in case anyone wants to achieve something similar.

[Working code with Default value](http://jsfiddle.net/R64bE/8/)

Basically all I had to do was send a default value for that field/cell in the first json I created.

```
jsonStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({
        data: {
            "identifier": "identify",
            "label": "description",
            "items": [
                {
                "identify": 123,
                "description": "Project Manager",
                "billingMethod":"Sample"},
            {
                "identify": 234,
                "description": "Developer"},
            {
                "identify": 536,
                "description": "Developer"}
            ]
        }
    });
```

Notice that all I had to do was add a value for that column in the json, i.e., for **Billing Method** Column, I added *"billingMethod":"Sample"* and it picks it up from there.

Cheers